# Typescript: How to make an array of objects adhere to an interface?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In the following snippet, `Product` is a Typescript interface. I would like to ensure every object in `products` adheres to that interface, but have no idea how. I've tried a few things like `products<Product[]>:` but nothing seems to work. I'm new to Typescript and would appreciate any help!

```
import * as faker from 'faker'
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid'

import { Product } from './models/Product'

export default {
  products: [
    {
      id: uuidv4(),
      name: faker.commerce.product(),
      description: faker.random.words(7),
      cents: faker.commerce.price(300, 15000),
      quantity: faker.random.number(15)
    }
  ]
}
```

**Edit:**

Simpler example per request

```
interface Product {
  id: string
  name: string
  quantity: string
}

export default {
  products: [ // How to make sure all objects in this array adhere to the Product interface above?
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Banana',
      quantity: 10
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Relevant issue is [microsoft/TypeScript#13626](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13626).  Please consider editing the above code to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone web IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) so that I can show you a solution/workaround that can be tested.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wGbINYFMqZQQhwDkWeUpAsAFCiSxwDecAbgCwroCuPwAE05wAvoWJk+gmrToB6OXACSKEgHMeuVKmAA7NXBgALYOjDJYdPTHxYAxrjgAFIgJ534zOnB+CAXCi6AJ4ANN4+usgguAGoMFB6amG0PnACWnYJYDDAELqx8YnJqQ66MKgFCfrFPgCOPMhlwDBBAbo8IABG+HQidHR2eXFwYK7u5QEuEG4eANoAunAAvHCz4Szrqf5wUkIcABQAlDWpcJHRART4AHSDINFQDtej0+NHJ6npqJnA2bn5mBwNygjQExGuAHdoAJUPsAOzHTY+UoTQGUW7EB5PUbABz7ADMAAZCSE4ABGACsxMJiJSpzg9UaORalyBUGuIN0YJA13aXXw+0ph3WfVo836tFwAA9GPB0lgeAAbTwjMYedAiIA) work for you?

Comment: Yes thank you. I was specifically curious if I could set something like `products<Product[]>: {...}` inline like that, but it seems I can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
interface Product {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    cents: number;
    quantity: number;
}

interface ProductCollection {
    products: Product[];
}

const collection: ProductCollection = {
    products: [
        {
            id: '1',
            name: 'something',
            description: 'An example',
            cents: 10,
            quantity: 1
        }
    ]
}

console.log(collection);
```

You can do it like that, alternatively you can just use `Product[]`.